# Redirect All emails to

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I have a test system in ubuntu that I want to redirect all emails to using PostFix, the following works, But I want to have multiple recipients, or to allow specific people to get emails.

edit /etc/postfix/main.cf and add

```
canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/canonical-redirect
```

create /etc/postfix/canonical-redirect and enter the address you want all emails sent to.

```
/^.*$/ email1@example.com

sudo postfix reload
```

I have tried following but doesn't work

```
person@example.com person@example.com         # to allow that persons emails to go through
/^.*$/ email1@example.com,email2@example.com  # to have 2 mails being replaced
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to replace only recipients addresses then it is better to use virtual alias maps instead of canonical address rewriting. See [VIRTUAL REAMDE](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) from postfix documentation.